# Db2 backup only transaction log files

Tags: backup, db2, transaction-log

What is the possibility to take transaction log (Archive log) backup in Db2 database.

I know that online backup takes archive log backup by default but what If I want the archive log backup after few hours of online incremental backup.

Comment: This question really belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I haven't use this fourm before. But thanks for advising the same. I will be careful next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this depends on how you are currently backing up your archive log files now.

If you currently have set LOGARCHMETH1 to `DISK:/path/`, Db2 simply archives log files that contain no active transactions to the specified path.  This is not a *backup*, this only moves the log files out of the active log path.  You still need to configure normal file system backups of the archive log path to protect the archive log files that you may need for a recovery.  **You can perform these backups as often as you require**, independently from database backups (i.e. `BACKUP DATABASE`).

If you're using an enterprise storage management product like TSM, NetBackup or similar, Db2 can leverage these and send the archive log files immediately to the storage manager – you would set LOGARCHMETH1 to a different value.  With this kind of configuration, your archive log files can be considered to be "backed up" as soon as the archiving process completes, as the files are no longer sitting on the primary database server.